# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I am building a portfolio website using React JS where I am supposed to call a API from sanity.io. But my React website is not able to fetch the data from Sanity. At that area of webpage where there should be data imported from Sanity Blog is actually a black screen. When I checked the console, there I found this error: Failed to load resource: `uwydqh1y.api.sanity.io/v1/data/query/produce?query=*%5B_type%3D%3D%22post%22%5D)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20slug%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mainImage%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20asset-%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D:1`  the server responded with a status of 400 ()
[image]

Here is the code written for About Page (where it was supposed to show my details I had entered in Sanity)

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from "react"
import sanityClient from "../client.js";
import myself from "../pic1.jpeg";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";
import BlockContent from "@sanity/block-content-to-react";

const builder=imageUrlBuilder(sanityClient);
function urlFor(source){
    return builder.image(source);
}

export default function About() {
   const [author,setAuthor]=useState(null);

   useEffect(()=>{
       sanityClient.fetch(`*[_type=="author"]{
           name,
           bio,
           "authorImage":image.asset->url
       }`).then((data)=>setAuthor(data[0]))
   },[]);

   if(!author) 
   return <div>Loading...</div>;
    
   return(
     <main className="relative">
    <img src={myself} alt="Myslef" 
    className="absolute w-full" />
    <div className="p-10 lg:pt-48 container mx-auto relative">
        <section className="bg-green-800 rounded-lg shadow-2xl lg:flex p-20">

        <img src={urlFor(author.authorImage).url()} 
        className="rounded w-32 h-32 lg:w-64 lg:h-64 mr-8" 
        alt={author.name} />
        <div className="text-lg flex flex-col justify-center">
            <h1 className="cursive text-6xl text-green-300 mb-4">
                Hey there. I'm{" "}
     <span className="text-green-100">{author.name}</span>
     </h1>
        <div className="prose lg:prose-xl text-white">
           <BlockContent blocks={author.bio} projectId="uwydqh1y" 
           dataset="produce" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        </div>
</main>
   )
}
```

Comment: If you post the response and request that shows up in the network tab it is easier for people to help with issues regarding network requests.

Status 400 means that what you are sending in the request is wrong and judging by the console log you aren't passing the correct data

Comment: 400 means you posted the wrong params to API, check your code, sanityClient.fetch(...) is it followed the Senity Docs?